# How Can I Add Autoprefix To Scoped Style In Vue

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-component

After deploying my vue app, I noticed the CSS doesn't behave uniformly across browsers, the CSS style used are in the Vue components, how can I apply Autoprefix to the style.

Comment: Are you using Vue CLI? https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#postcss

Comment: you can use something like sass auto prefix https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-autoprefixer or you can do it manually or refactor to styled-components it will auto prefix for you